# Is there a way to hardcode the masterpage to change/remove the top left 'Sharepoint' text?

Tags: master-page, branding

We can do it in few lines of powershell:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://tozit-sp:2015
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "Awesome Text Goes Here"
$webApp.Update()
```

I want to know if there is any method like:-

a.  delegate controls

b.  hardcode changes to masterpage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hardcoding is never a nice solution!

Look in to the `SuiteBarBrandingDelegate` control:

Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <!-- SuiteBarBrandingDelegate (the top-left "SharePoint" text on a page) -->
  <Control ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/15/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/SuiteBarBrandingDelegate.ascx"
           Id="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate"
           Sequence="1" />

</Elements>
```

SuiteBarBrandingDelegate.ascx:

```
<div class="ms-core-brandingText" id="BrandingTextControl" runat="server" />
```

SuiteBarBrandingDelegate.ascx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BrandingTextControl.Controls.Add(new Literal
    {
        Text = string.Format("<a href='{0}'><img src='{1}' alt='{2}' /></a>",
        SPContext.Current.Site.Url,
        "/_layouts/15/images/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/tozit36light.png",
        SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Title)
    });
}
```

Basically you choose what to render in the code behind file.

All code from http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages

on that link you also find delegates for all other new SP 2013 delegates

Comment: Can you add to this that "a not recommended option is to set the visibility of this delegate tag to false".

Answer (score 3):

b. You can remove this in Master page:
`<SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" ControlId="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" runat="server"/>`
Instead paste needed text.
Use Microsoft Sharepoint Designer to do this.